# How to update the chart dynamically with vue-chartjs?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm using `vue.js` and `vue-chartjs` for the first time. 
In the simplified code example I want to add a label to the chart by pressing the `add Label` button, but the chart is not updating. My code is based on [this](https://pusher.com/tutorials/data-visualization-vue-chart) tutorial.

I tried calling the `render` method from the child component, but that does not work.

[image: Edit Vue Chart.js add label]

I expected that when I click the `add Label` button that the label `13` will be added to the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your code. First if you want to call a method from child component you have to use special attribute `ref`. Please see more about [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

So in your code it should be:

```
<template>
  ...
  <chart ref='chart' :chart-data="datacollection"></chart>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  ...
  this.$refs.chart.render() // Not Chart.render()
  ...
</script>
```

Second you have a typo in your Chart.js:

```
this.chartData // Not this.chartdata
```

So this means yours `render` method in `mounted` is not working and unnecessary. Your chart is already drawn by `reactiveProp` after you set `chartData` prop.

But unfortunately this:

```
this.datacollection.labels.push(13);
```

still not work. If you looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/blob/develop/src/mixins/index.js#L87) you will see the library use watcher on `chartData` only. It means if you change entire of `chartData` this will work fine (as it works at first drawn). Please see more about [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch).

So if you want to rely on `reactiveProp` then when you want update `labels` you should set:

```
this.datacollection = {
  ...this.datacollection,
  labels: this.datacollection.labels.concat(13) // avoid to mutate data
}
```

[image: Edit Vue Chart.js add label]

Comment: It seems they intentionally avoid to use `deep` attribute in watcher for performance. https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/416

Answer (score 4):

What helped me was adding a `v-if="loaded"`, which you will set to `false` before your change. Then, after your change, set it to `false`.